# check response status from LWP::UserAgent response

Tags: perl

LWP::UserAgent using we are sending request to an endpoint which is sending the response as `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` or `HTTP/1.1 200 200`. I used pattern match to check the response the status.

But I was thinking to use some common function from which we can check the status of response instead of having pattern match in the HTTP STATUS. Below is the code which I have .

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( );
$ua->timeout(30);
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "$EndPoint");
$req->content_type('text/xml');
$req->content($send_data);
my $response = $ua->request($req);

my $http_status = '';
if ( $response =~ m/^HTTP.*?\s(.*)/ ) {
  $http_status = uc($1);  # It is probably already upper case -- just making sure.
}

if ( $http_status =~ m/200/ ) {
  if ( $response =~ m/Status=\"Successful\"/ ) {
    print "Successful\n";
  } else {
    my $error_code = '';
    if ( $response =~ m/Error Code=\"(.+?)\"/ ) {
      print  "Error: $1 \n";
    }
}
```

I tried to use below code to check the status but I am getting error  `Can't locate object method "is_success" via package "HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

```
 if($response->is_success){
      print Dumper($response);
     } else {
      print Dumper($response->status_line);
     }
```

**Edit**

```
perl send_request.pl
Can't locate object method "is_success" via package "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

**##I added a print on $response**

```
  Connection: close
    Date: Mon, 10 Jan 2022 17:36:58 GMT
    Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
    Server: Apache
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Length: 356
    Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
    Client-Date: Mon, 10 Jan 2022 17:36:58 GMT
    Client-Peer: XXXXX
    Client-Response-Num: 1
    SOAPAction: ""
```

Comment: I'm a maintainer of LWP. This might be a bug in LWP::UserAgent. `$ua->request` should return an HTTP::Response object. I think ideally you would raise a ticket on https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl/issues and add some more details, such as which version of LWP::UserAgent you are running, and what the response body (or at least the headers) of the request you are sending are. Thanks.

Comment: Is something wrong with `if ($response->is_success)` ... ? (it's right in synopsis)

Comment: Re "*Can't locate object method "is_success" via package*",  No, using `$response->is_success` in the code you posted would not result in that error.

Comment: What do you see if you print the contents of `$response` immediately after setting it?

Comment: @simbabque I have created https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl/issues/403

Comment: @DaveCross I have updated the question with $response

Comment: Please stop adding false information. You already had a program that couldn't run, and now you add output that couldn't be obtained. Please edit your question to include an actual demonstration of the problem. We can't help you if you if what you post is made up.

Comment: @ikegami What do you mean by made up ?  I am posting what i can see and what issue I am facing .

Comment: Re "*What do you mean by made up ?*", The code you posted isn't the code you ran. It doesn't include the error that lead you to get the error you're asking about. And the output you posted isn't the output you got. (The output part has since been fixed.)

Comment: @ikegami I don't know what proof you want but this is not made up , I am getting this error that's why i posted here .

Comment: @Developer  If the code you added, `my $response = $ua->get('http://example.com'); if ($response->is_success) ...`, gives you an error then something is badly broken with your system/installation.  How do youo run that?  Can you post a complete (while minimal) such program? What versions of software do you use, on what system?

Comment: Re "*I don't know what proof you want*", A program that actually outputs `Can't locate object method "is_success" [...]`, for starters. See [mcve].  // Re "*but this is not made up*", Please don't lie. This isn't the program you ran. It doesn't even include `$response->is_success`!

Comment: @zdim I have mentioned the example of the code from where I got .

Comment: "_I have mentioned the example of the code from where I got_"  -- yes, thank you, In normal circumstances that really shouldn't throw errors though.  So I'm asking for a complete program in which that fails for you  (I mean complete as copy-paste-run.)  It should be below a dozen lines ... can you add that?

Comment: @zdim I have updated the code now.

Comment: Thank you for updating, but that snippet with `if($response->is_success)` is _not a complete runnable program_.  That's just an example which can't fail. So if you say that it is failing then we can't help you out because we can't see a reason why it's failing.

Comment: @zdim Thank you . this is the whole code I am using it is throwing the error Can't locate object method "is_success" via package "HTTP/1.1 200 OK. So look like $response is not a object it is a string . But I am not sure how we can handle that . That's why I added a question to get some help.

Comment: @zdim I am using LWP::UserAgent version 5.833 installed on linux server. May be a installation but I can't say that .

Comment: "_this is the whole code I am using_" -- seems like we are not understanding each other.  That snippet with `is_success` _cannot_ be the whole program.  (What is `$request` in it?)  The code you posted originally isn't runnable either (what's `$EndPoint` ?) -- and you are saying you added `is_success` to that and it fails?  That means something earlier is wrong so we need a _whole runnable program._  I can't tell what's wrong by looking at what you posted.

Comment: @zdim I can't share the whole endpoint of $Endpoint even if I share with you , you can't connect it because it is in DMZ. that's why I haven't shared that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240931/discussion-between-developer-and-zdim).

Comment: Thanks but I have to go back to my work here :)  Hopefully someone else takes it ...  Something's failing early on, perhaps that `$req` object isn't valid.   Test for _every_ statement from the very beginning

Comment: @zdim when I am using pattern match everything is working fine . Only issue I am having when I am trying to use is_success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't stringify the response then use pattern matches. Use the provided methods instead.

To check for a 2xx code:

```perl
if ( $response->is_success ) { ... }
```

To check for 200 specifically (in the rare event you want to distinguish `200 OK` from `201 Created`),

```perl
if ( $response->code == 200 ) { ... }
```

If you want the string that follows, you can use

```perl
$response->status_line   # "200 OK" or "200 200"
```

Comment: Can't locate object method "status_code" via package "HTTP::Headers" at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/HTTP/Message.pm line 658.

Comment: My bad, should be `code`. (Fixed.) But you shouldn't use that line. Why do you think this is the rare situation you want to check for 201?

Comment: I don't want to have pattern match because the third party tomcat service can send response like 200 200 or 200 OK . So I was trying to find a generic method which can do that

Comment: By "line", I meant "line of code I posted that checks the code"...

Answer (score 2):

There are methods to query the response, you rarely ever need to parse its message.

A `LWP::UserAgent::get` returns an [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object.  In its documentation we find

`is_success`, `is_info`, `is_error`, `is_client_error`, `is_server_error`, `is_redirect`

The most commonly used is `is_success`, with an example right in the synopsis.

More details on what exactly these mean are in [HTTP::Status](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Status)